# How to define a for loop in pseudocode?

Tags: algorithms

I hope this is the right place to ask this question, if not i'd be glad if you could direct me to the appropriate stack site:)

I'm trying to formulate R code as Pseudo code but am uncertain about how to define a for-loop. Below you can find my current set up.

[image: code]

So basically what this code does is to calculate the accessibility for all zones within a study region. Therefore it does the for loop for each zone. However, I do not know what is the right way to formulate this, i.e. I'm uncertain if my "element in 1...Z_n" makes sense. I have not been able to figure out what the right formulation would be for a loop like this.

In R it is simply `for i in zones` and `zones` being a vector with all the zone ID's.
tt_{i,j} stands for the travel time between zone i and zone j (j is also part of the same vector).

The rest of the code looks like this if it helps somehow:

```
for (i in unique(tt_atod$source)) {
  temp <- subset(tt_atod, tt_atod$source==i & tt_atod$travel_time <= 1800)
  temp$rest_time <- 900-temp$travel_time 
  temp$ratio <- temp$rest_time/temp$tt_walk
  temp$ratio <- ifelse(temp$ratio>=1, 1, temp$ratio)
  temp$opp_ratio <- temp$ratio*temp$opportun
  reachableopportun <- round(sum(temp$opp_ratio), digits=0)
  tt_atod$accessibility <- ifelse(tt_atod$source==i, reachableopportun, tt_atod$accessibility )
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: for pseudocode, makes sense. Lots of modern languages, like Python, support iteration of objects directly from containers, should not be a problem for anyone with programming background to understand what you are doing.

Comment: but is it obvious what Z is for like this? I know how to code (at least i get it running) but writing in mathematical terms is not my strenght.

Comment: Consider just looping likr `for i = 0 to n`, then you can describe what $z_i$ is separately